# fazer o javascript escutar um elemento html e manipular o valor da propriedade de outro elemento se houver click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso escutar um elemento html de id="hamburger", se o usuário clicar, o javascript verifica qual o valor da propriedade display de outro elemento, no caso id="OverlayNav", e altera o valor, caso display="none" transforma em "block" e vice versa.

tá dando erro de sintaxe, alguém pode exemplificar como faço isso acontecer?

gostaria de tornar todo o box do meu OverlayNav sensível ao click, para caso o usuário clicar em qualquer área de tela onde não houver um `<li>`, o display do OverlayNav se torne "none" tbm

```
<!-- Script do OverlayNav -->    

<script>
    document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var status = OverlayNav.style.display = '';
        if (status === 'none') {
            var status = OverlayNav.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            var status = OverlayNav.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se código tinha alguns erros, o primeiro é que vc não declarou a variável pro `OverlayNav` depois que vc colocou a variável `status = OverlayNav.style.display = ''` como um valor `= ''` e vc pode simplesmente colocar a variável como `OverlayNav.style.display` e deixa pra setar o `none` ou `block` na condição `if/else`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se vc quer que clicando no `OverlayNav` ele suma vc coloca outro *listener* com uma função de clique nele para caso seja clicado ele fique com `display:none`

```js
var OverlayNav = document.getElementById("OverlayNav");

OverlayNav.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
})


document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var status = OverlayNav.style.display;

  if (status == 'none') {
      OverlayNav.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      OverlayNav.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="hamburger">hamburger</div>

<div id="OverlayNav">OverlayNav</div>
```

Comment: como vc comentou, nem precisaria criar uma nova `var status` onde está mudando o `display` do elemento, ficaria até melhor :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual vdd, na verdade é que como parti do código dele nem me atendei aos detalhes

Comment: eu entendi. aliás acho muito legal esse gifs animados

Comment: @RicardoPontual é um programinha de 3MB chama ScreenToGif, super leve e fácil de usar, recomendo

Comment: boa recomendação, baixando aqui :)

Comment: legal, funcionou =D
outro detalhe, existe um script que muda a classe do botão hamburger quando clicado, this.classList.toggle("is-active");
quando clica na box do overlay, ele some mas o botão continua com a classe ("is-active") como volto a classe do botão caso o overlay seja display:none ?

Comment: @NicholasAffonso na função que vc clica no overlay vc coloca dentro para remover a classe is-active do hamburger, ficaria assim por exemplo `document.getElementById("hamburger").classList.remove('is-active');`, vc tem que executar isso quando clicar no overlay

Comment: perfeito, tudo funcionando de acordo